# Google Sheets API recognize end of sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I add rows to a Google Sheet via the API. For this, I use C# Google.API.Sheets.v4 NuGet package. I pretty much calculate the cells where I want to write in myself.

My problem is that when I reach the end of the worksheet, I don't know this in my application. There doesn't seem to be an error or anything. Data is just lost!

When I use my sheet without the API I would notice and just press this button:

[image: I mean this bottom functionality]

I want to either add 1 row before writing one row in my application or recognize that the end of the worksheet is reached.

The code looks pretty much like the update code provided here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

I use the spreadsheets.values.update functionality and write into a bottom row that doesn't yet exist

**So again in short: I need the "more rows at bottom" functionality somehow in my application**

Bonus Question: I lost some data because of this problem. Any ideas on how to recover it?

Comment: Without seeing how you write rows/values we can't really say how to improve. Just know that you can obtain the relevant max rows and columns from a spreadsheets.get call, and so you should be able to determine when you're adding more rows than are available.

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch you are right. I first didn't want to provide a code sample because it's pretty much like in the documentation but it still might have helped in that case

Answer (score 0):

I found a sattisfying workaround. Instead of using the spreadsheets.values.update functionality I use the spreadsheets.values.append functionality as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append).

It is important to set it to InsertDataOptionEnum.OVERWRITE to mimic the behaviour or you'll end up having each new cell in a separate row.

OLD ( uses .Update() )

```
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);
request.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
```

NEW ( uses .Append() )

```
//use AppendRequest instead of UpdateRequest to avoid lost lines on end of sheet
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, spreadsheetId, range);
request.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
request.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.OVERWRITE; //overwrite when writing cells or it will be new line per cell
```